# serve a GWT application from the app server root

Tags: apache, gwt, jetty

I have a GWT application, which I deploy as a WAR file to a Jetty 8 server.

I want it to be accessible via

```
http://<myserver>/
```

instead of

```
http://<myserver>:8080/MyApp/MyApp.html
```

I understand I can configure Jetty to run on port 80 instead of 8080 or have an apache instance running on port 80 and forwarding requests to Jetty running on 8080 (don't see a benefit of the latter, though).
but how can I deploy the GWT app to be accessible at the server ROOT?

so far I see I can create myapp.xml in Jetty/contexts folder and put

```
<Set name="contextPath">/</Set>
```

there. I can also rename MyApp.html to index.html. but I'm not sure this is the "recommended" approach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, accepting my own answer:
    create myapp.xml in Jetty/contexts folder

thank you, Chris!

Answer (score 3):

I think you pretty much answered your own question:

The application server (e.g. Jetty) is responsible for the context path, so you must set it somehow in the application server. This is different for each server, e.g. in Tomcat one possibility to achieve this is renaming the war file to ROOT.war. (I don't know all the possible ways how to do this in Jetty off-hand.)

**Note**: The file that is served when going directly to the context URL can be determined in your `web.xml`, using

```xml
<welcome-file-list>
  <welcome-file>MyApp.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

So you don't have to rename it to index.html.